# c# overiding a methond in a Referenced library

Tags: c#, dll, overriding, .net-assembly

I am programming an application that checks some data in a DB (the DB continuously updated).
For getting the data from the DB I am using an assembley (.dll file) programmed by another team (I can't get/change the code of the .dll file).

I want to "stress test" my algorithem/porgram with my own data (extreme data), I can't change the DB.
a simplified code example:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //timer1.Interval = 10000
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable values = someLib.GetData(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),DateTime.Now);
        CheckData(values); //checking the data form the DB, I want to "stress test" this function/logic.

    }
}
```

I want someLib.GetData function to return a specific data (ment to check my program).
I can write a new function that returns the same DataTable like someLib.GetData (same colums etc.) but with my own data, the problem is that this solution requires to manually check all the occurrences of GetData (and more functions that take data from the DB) and change them manually.
I am searching for some systematic way for approaching this.
Another way I thought of is to just delete the reference and "repair" all the errors, the problem is there is a lot of functions I am using in the aforementioned library that I am still in need of.

My qustion is, is there any way to override/disable a function/s (or even whole classes) from an assembly I dont have the code of?

Thank you.

EDIT: the method/s are not virtual.

Comment: _"is there any way to override/disable a function/s (or even whole classes) from an assembly I dont have the code of?"_ -- whether you have the code or not isn't the issue. The question is whether the thing you want to override is `virtual` or not. If it's not, then no. That said, this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you _really_ seem to be asking is how to mock the database. it's too broad to be a suitable question here, but see https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20mock%20database.

Comment: Of course, it is called inheritance. You could also [override](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) or [hide](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) methods, if the library allows it.

Comment: Maybe I shold have mentiond it ( I will edit the post), the methos/s are not virtual.
regarding the database, you are right that this a some kind of XY problem.
That is because this is a simplified information about the system I working with.
Its not just a DB but a massive system that generates the data (online) checking it and writing it to the DB.
I already checked the solutions that dont require me to change my code (and I of course prefer), there is no easy way to mock to the DB/ data generating program/ anything else in the system, unfortunately.

Comment: @Alexander I can inherit from the base class but it still leave the base methos/s problem.
my problem is that there is a lot of calls to GetData (and more methods) scattered around my program.
if I want to creace a new method (with or without inheriting from the base class) I need to manually search for all the calls to the base class method and change it.
This leave the option for me to "miss" some calls, I need a way to override (that means, a call to the base class will get to my progrramed methos) or disable the base class (and repair all the errors).

Comment: @Alexander there are [gotchas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords) when _hiding_

Comment: Then you need to mock the library.

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution (if I understand the problem correctly):

```cs
public class MyLib {
  public SomeLib someLib { get; set; }

  public MyLib (SomeLib someLib) {
    this.someLib = someLib;
  }

  public void methodFromSomeLibWhichIsRequired(...) {
    return someLib.methodFromSomeLibWhichIsRequired(...);
  }

  // ... so on for any used methods of SomeLib

  public DataTable getData() {
    // my own implementation of method of SomeLib
  }
}
```

Than all that you need is change the declaration of your SomeLib instance to MyLib instance, i.e. instead of

```cs
SomeLib someLib = new SomeLib();
```

use this

```cs
MyLib someLib = new MyLib(new SomeLib());
```

So you don't need to change the name of `someLib` everywhere and you just implement those methods in your `MyLib` which you need from `SomeLib`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a good start in the right direction.
That being said, in the library I am working with, Somelib is a static class.
Any ideas to work with this situation with minimal changes to the actual program? (I don't mind adding more code/ classes like you reccomended).

Comment: It seems I become misleading. I don't understand what do you need. You have a 3rd party lib which is often used in your code and you want to change results of some methods with your own without any actions from your side? How it can be? Maybe you should reconsider your question and give some more code and explanations what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Implementation of 3rd party libs in own code sometimes require using Facade, Proxy or Adapter patterns. But all this requires some actions from developer...